# how will I put the conditionals in file handling python

Tags: python

so this is my code so far (I know it's not that clean forgive me):

```
name = input("Enter Name: ")
course = input("Enter Course: ")
section = input("Enter Section: ")
sub1 = int(input("Enter 1st Grade: "))
sub2 = int(input("Enter 2nd Grade: "))
sub3 = int(input("Enter 3rd Grade: "))
sub4 = int(input("Enter 4th Grade: "))
sub5 = int(input("Enter 5th Grade: "))
avg = int((sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5)/5)
print("Average mark:",avg)
if avg >=70:
   print("Remarks: Passed")
else:
   print("Remarks: Failed")
f = open("test.txt", "w+")
f.write(name)
f.write('\n')
f.write(course)
f.write('\n')
f.write(section)
f.write('\n')
f.write("The average is: ")
f.write(str(avg))
f.write('\n')
f.write("Remarks: ")
f = open("test.txt","r")
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

and this was supposed to be the example outcome of the txt file:

```
Juan deal Cruz
IT0011
A
The average is 80
Remarks: Passed
```

but the problem is that I don't know how to put the remarks on the `f.write` itself

Comment: Please read [ask], supply the actual output and any errors you get, and please please please format your code properly. There are instructions for how to do all this when you [edit] the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre], meaning input (if required), less code, and undesired output. You can [edit] the question, although I'm glad you've already gotten a good answer by OneCricketeer.

Answer (score 1):

Use another variable and carry it through to where you want it

```
passed = avg >= 70
passed_str = "Passed" if passed else "Failed" 
print("Remarks: " + passed_str)
...
f.write("Remarks: " + passed_str)
f.write('\n')
```

Or use an if else like you already did for your print statement